# How to plot with different linestyles in pylab

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have these two `numpy` arrays

```
  import numpy as np
  a=np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
  b=np.array([-1,-2,-3,-4,-5,1,2,-3,-4])
```

I can easily plot them like so

```
  from pylab import *
  plot(a,b,'b-',lw=2)
```

I would like to show the points with negative `b` with a different linestyles, for instance a dashed line.

I could do this

```
 plot(a[(b<0)],b[(b<0)],'b--',lw=2)
```

but this connects all the points in a single line. For instance, I don't want the point with a=5 and b=-4 connected with the point with a=8 and b=-3

Comment: Its in their documentation last time, I checked. Just check it out.

Comment: So you want one plot through all points but with varying line style?

Comment: @LevLevitsky: yes, that's right

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9284877/change-matplotlib-line-style-mid-graph

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use mask array:

```
import numpy as np
a=np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
b=np.array([-1,-2,-3,-4,-5,1,2,-3,-4])

plot(a, b)
m = b > 0
plot(np.ma.array(a, mask=m), np.ma.array(b, mask=m), 'r--', lw=2)
```

[image]

However, I think this maybe not what you want. Here is a quick method that can split the lines into two parts:

```
import numpy as np
a=np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
b=np.array([-1,-2,-3,-4,-5,1,2,-3,-4])

x = np.linspace(a.min(), a.max(), 1000)
y = np.interp(x, a, b)

m = y <= 0
plot(np.ma.array(x, mask=m), np.ma.array(y, mask=m), 'b-', lw=2)
m = y > 0
plot(np.ma.array(x, mask=m), np.ma.array(y, mask=m), 'r--', lw=2)
```

[image]

`np.interp()` will use many memory for large dataset, here is another method that find all zero points. The output is the same as above.

```
idx1 = np.where(b[1:] * b[:-1] < 0)[0]
idx2 = idx1 + 1

x0 = a[idx1] + np.abs(b[idx1] / (b[idx2] - b[idx1])) * (a[idx2] - a[idx1]) 

a2 = np.insert(a, idx2, x0)
b2 = np.insert(b, idx2, 0)

m = b2 < 0
plot(np.ma.array(a2, mask=m), np.ma.array(b2, mask=m), 'b-', lw=2)
m = b2 > 0
plot(np.ma.array(a2, mask=m), np.ma.array(b2, mask=m), 'r--', lw=2)
```