# Changing line style for certain range of values using matplotlib

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, plot

I need to reproduce plots of this type (bifurcation plots) -

[image: bifurcation plot]

I tried to follow the example given at [change-matplotlib-line-style-mid-graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9284877/change-matplotlib-line-style-mid-graph), but couldn't really work it out. Could someone give a tip?

Comment: What exactly could you not work out? The trick is to draw 4 lines (in your example): 2 solid ones and 2 dashed ones.

Comment: I don't understand in the link I have given what is the line `plt.plot(x[below], y1[below], 'b--')` does..

Comment: in the example that you linked, `below` is a vector of `bool`s that is used to select only those values in `x` and `y` for which `below` is `True`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the following I have put together 4 different examples. They show different things:

1. The simplest way to recreate the graph in your question. Note, that each line is only defined by two points.
2. This is what I assume you have: two x and y vectors that define each line (in my example they each have 100 values).
3. This one is most interesting for you (I guess): The vectors `solid1` and `solid2` are used to select the values of x and y, that satisfy the conditions.
4. Just to show you how you can put the spines in the center (since the graph in your question has them centered).

[image]

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure(figsize=(12,4))

# Example 1
plt.subplot(1,4,1)
line1 = np.array([[-1,0],[0,0]])
line2 = np.array([[0,0],[1,1]])
line3 = np.array([[-1,-1],[0,0]])
line4 = np.array([[0,0],[1,0]])
plt.plot(line1[:,0], line1[:,1], 'b', linewidth=4)
plt.plot(line2[:,0], line2[:,1], 'b', linewidth=4)
plt.plot(line3[:,0], line3[:,1], 'b--', linewidth=4)
plt.plot(line4[:,0], line4[:,1], 'b--', linewidth=4)

# Example 2
plt.subplot(1,4,2)
x1 = np.linspace(-1,1,100)
x2 = np.linspace(-1,1,100)
y1 = x1*0
y2 = x2
plt.plot(x1,y1,'r', linewidth=4)
plt.plot(x2,y2,'g', linewidth=4)

# Example 3
plt.subplot(1,4,3)
#some sort of split condition:
solid1 = x1<0
solid2 = x2>0
#plot each line in two seperate plot calls
plt.plot(x1[solid1], y1[solid1], 'r', linewidth=4)
plt.plot(x1[np.logical_not(solid1)], y1[np.logical_not(solid1)], 'r--', linewidth=4)
plt.plot(x2[solid2], y2[solid2], 'g', linewidth=4)
plt.plot(x2[np.logical_not(solid2)], y2[np.logical_not(solid2)], 'g--', linewidth=4)

# Example 4 
plt.subplot(1,4,4)
# put the spines to the middle
ax = plt.gca()
ax.spines['left'].set_position('center')
ax.spines['right'].set_color('none')
ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('center')
ax.spines['top'].set_color('none')
ax.spines['left'].set_smart_bounds(True)
ax.spines['bottom'].set_smart_bounds(True)
ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')
ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('left')

plt.show()
```