# Matplotlib challenge - changing line style in contour map

Tags: python, matplotlib, contour

I would like to use numpy's boolean indexing to plot only regions of a function in which I have a certain condition met - sigma < 0, as in the code bellow. When I try to use numpy's boolean indexing as in this example - [change_line_style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9284877/change-matplotlib-line-style-mid-graph), I get TypeError. Is there a way to use numpy's boolean indexing to plot only certain regions using the contour function?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import rc
rc('font',**{'family':'sans-serif','sans-serif':['Helvetica']})
rc('text', usetex=True)

plt.figure()
plt.ylim([-2,2])
plt.xlim([-0.5,0.5])

plt.xlabel(r'\lambda')
plt.ylabel(r'u')

lambda_x = np.linspace(-0.5,0.5,1000)
u = np.linspace(-2,2,1000)

X,Y = np.meshgrid(lambda_x,u)
# Drawing f=0 lines for implicit function f(u;lambda) = lambda*u  + u**3 - u**5
f1 = X  + Y**2 - Y**4
f2 = Y

sigma = X + 3*Y**2 - 5*Y**4

stable = sigma < 0
#plt.setp(zc, linewidth=4)
print stable.shape
print f1.shape

plt.contour(X[stable],Y[stable], f1[stable], levels = [0],colors = ('r'),linewidths = 4,extend='both')
plt.contour(X[stable],Y[stable], f2[stable], levels = [0],colors = ('b'),linewidths = 4,extend='both')

plt.show()
```

Comment: Can you not prepare the data inbeofre?

Comment: I can't find the minimal example here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it!

I used numpy.ma.masked_where() function, as in this piece of code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import rc
rc('font',**{'family':'sans-serif','sans-serif':['Helvetica']})
rc('text', usetex=True)

plt.figure()
plt.ylim([-2,2])
plt.xlim([-0.5,0.5])

lambda_x = np.linspace(-0.5,0.5,1000)
u = np.linspace(-2,2,1000)

X,Y = np.meshgrid(lambda_x,u)
# Drawing f=0 lines for implicit function f(u;lambda) = lambda*u  + u**3 - u**5
f1 = X  + Y**2 - Y**4
f2 = Y

sigma = X + 3*Y**2 - 5*Y**4

unstable = sigma > 0
stable = sigma < 0

#for i in range(0,10):
    #f1[i] = f1[i][stable[i]]

plt.contour(np.ma.masked_where(unstable, X),np.ma.masked_where(unstable, Y), np.ma.masked_where(unstable, f1), levels = [0],colors = ('r'),linewidths = 4,extend='both')
plt.contour(np.ma.masked_where(stable, X),np.ma.masked_where(stable, Y), np.ma.masked_where(stable, f1), levels = [0],colors = ('b'),linewidths = 4,linestyles = 'dashed',extend='both')
plt.contour(np.ma.masked_where(unstable, X),np.ma.masked_where(unstable, Y), np.ma.masked_where(unstable, f2), levels = [0],colors = ('r'),linewidths = 4,extend='both')
plt.contour(np.ma.masked_where(stable, X),np.ma.masked_where(stable, Y), np.ma.masked_where(stable, f2), levels = [0],colors = ('b'),linewidths = 4,linestyles = 'dashed',extend='both')

plt.show()
```